# Copy & Paste in place from Illustrator to Photoshop - Got blurred

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, favicon

I am trying to copy & paste the icon from Illustrator into Photoshop, it looks blurred.

I have checked the size of the icon and pixel perfect of the grid, but still I face the problem.

It would be great if anyone offer to me a right way? Please welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Save the Illustrator file as an EPS, AI, or PDF

Use the File > Place Embedded command, to insert it into your PS document as a Smart Object.